# iframe - weird src - data:image/png - how it gets parsed

Tags: javascript, jquery

i saw this:

```
<iframe src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAJCAYAAADgkQYQAAAAFElEQVQYV2P8DwQMBADjqCKiggAAmZsj5vuXmnUAAAAASUVORK5CYII="></iframe>
```

and this will be rendered in html as real url,

how does this weird thing work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `data URI`, which is a resource, typically `an image, embedded` in the `URI` as opposed to one loaded from an `external URL.`

`iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAJCAYAAADgkQYQAAAAFElEQVQYV2P8DwQMBADjqCKiggAAmZsj5vuXmnUAAAAASUVORK5CYII`   is  `sResourceData` for this `iframe`.

**what is sResourceData:**  A text-representation of the data of the resource, where content is represented as URL-allowed characters. Unsafe characters must be percent-encoded.

If src is set to base64 it tells that the data specified by the sResourceData parameter is encoded as base64; otherwise, the data is assumed to be percent-encoded.

for more info read this:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's a data URI - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs

They "allow content creators to embed small files inline in documents". (quote from MDN)